# special touch effects for buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-drawable

I wanted to create touch effects exactly like "Cooler Master - Cooling Android" app. It's clear that it's more than just using a simple drawable.

I searched a lot and I think I should make a class that extends Button and use a layout XML file for that button, but there are things like how that button understands point we have touched it or how it changes the button's background with duration from that point?? And there's also a round touch effect for the back button in Actionbar.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the ripple effect introduced in materials (API 21)?

Comment: it's like ripple effect but my device is api 19 and those effects work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

We have used the [Navasmdc MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) with great success

Comment: how can i import this library in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

The ripple is pretty simple to mimic on older devices. You have to do three things:

1. Create a ripple drawable, which simply draws a circle starting from one specific point.
2. In your view override drawableStateChanged(). When the state changes to pressed, start ripple's animation. When the state changes to not pressed, finish the animation.
3. In onTouchEvent set the hotspot for the ripple.

For an example see:

- RippleDrawable: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/drawable/RippleDrawable.java
- Button with ripple support: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/widget/Button.java
- State change causing ripples to animate: https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/animation/RippleStateAnimator.java

And the animation in action: [click to go to YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-KHZjT4C5Y)